# Wrapping multiple created elements with .wrapAll

Tags: jquery

the first object selected is not being recognized, but the remainder are

```
$(links).next(date).next(breakline).andSelf().wrapAll('<span class="mangaLine">');
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?  `.nextUntil()` may be more appropriate here (and cheaper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you want, and it may depend on your exact HTML structure and sectors, but I think you need to add an additional `andSelf()` after the first `next`:

```
$(links).next(date).andSelf().next(breakline).andSelf().wrapAll('<span class="mangaLine">');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the previous object in the chain as well with another [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) call, like this:

```
$(links).next(date).andSelf()                  //add links back
        .next(breakline).andSelf()             //add dates and links back
        .wrapAll('<span class="mangaLine">');
```

[`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) only adds the `.prevObject` in the chain, it can't hop back more than one step, so you need to get the chain before as well.  There are a few work-arounds with chaining, I just did that *I* thought looked cleanest above.

Comment: @RoToRa - it would, I was making a demo when I realized it, updated to be a bit cleaner

Comment: Yes, it's ok now. You edit really fast. I saw at least 2  previous versions of your answer :-)